# C++ how do I terminate my programm using ESC button

Tags: c++, console-application, keypress, exit, terminate

Here is my main function i use visual studio 2012 express and the code works fine. My question is how will i terminate this loop when the user Presses the ESC button instead of -1. Although i would prefer a solution that works both in unix and windows, if it is not possible i am most interested in it working for windows.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
list mylist;

int value;
cout<<"Give the numbers you want to insert to the list, press -1 to stop\n";
do
{
    cin>>value;
    mylist.insertf(value);
    mylist.sort_list();
    mylist.print();
}while(value!=-1);




}
```

Comment: Nothing in standard C++ will do that.

Comment: what do you mean by standard. sorry i am mostly new in C++

Comment: Anything you can do by only using standard C++ libraries and language features with no third party ones. Basically the ones that should ship with every implementation.

Comment: do you know how it can happen with a third party library?

Comment: @Kostas check i posted working solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here are solution for Windows**

### First solution:

**Esc will not be handled when user starts to type till pressing enter. 
While idle Esc will be handled**

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <vector>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int value=0;
    std::vector<int> mylist; 
    do
    {   
        //check if any input.
        if (_kbhit()){
            //probable user started to type 
            //block to read till the user press Enter. If you want to handle Esc here .
            //then you should manually do input reading . I will write that solution later
            std::cin>>value; 
            //if success
            if(std::cin.good()){ 
                mylist.push_back(value); 
            }else{
                //firstly, clear error flag 
                std::cin.clear();
                //ignore 
                std::cin.ignore(10000,'\n');

            }

            //print  list
            std::cout<<"new list: { " ;
            for(int i=0;i< mylist.size();i++){
                std::cout<<mylist[i]<<'\t';
            }
            std::cout<<" }"<<std::endl;
        }

        //check if Esc Pressed
    }while(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE)==0);

    return 0;
}
```

### Second Solution:

**Esc will be handled always in another thread. Immediate exit can be undesirable on some cases**

```
DWORD WINAPI CheckEscape( LPVOID lpParam ) {
        while(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE)==0){
            //sleep 
            Sleep(10);
        }
        exit(0);

}



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int value=0;
    std::vector<int> mylist; 
    //create thread for handling ESC key
    CreateThread( NULL, 0, CheckEscape,NULL  , 0, NULL);

    //loop infinitely
    while(true)
    {    
            std::cin>>value; 
            //if success
            if(std::cin.good()){ 
                mylist.push_back(value); 
            }else{
                //firstly, clear error flag 
                std::cin.clear();
                //ignore 
                std::cin.ignore(10000,'\n');

            }

            //print  list
            std::cout<<"new list: { " ;
            for(int i=0;i< mylist.size();i++){
                std::cout<<mylist[i]<<'\t';
            }
            std::cout<<" }"<<std::endl;
        }  
    return 0;
}
```

### Third Solution and **the Best one** .Do everything manually

**Handling keypress manually.
Exit will be called when Esc is Pressed. You can change it to handle more right way**

```
bool keypress( char &key){
    INPUT_RECORD IR[1];
    DWORD read;
    static HANDLE h = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    while(PeekConsoleInputA(h,IR,1,&read)){
        if(read!=0){
            //check if it was Key Event
            if(IR[0].EventType==KEY_EVENT){
                key=IR[0].Event.KeyEvent.uChar.AsciiChar; 
                ReadConsoleInputA(h,IR,1,&read);
                FlushConsoleInputBuffer(h);
                return true;
            }
            if(ReadConsoleInputA(h,IR,1,&read)){
                continue; 
            }
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}

//getnumber
int cinnumb( ){
    char buffer[32];
    buffer[0]='\0';
    int count=0;
    DWORD key=-1;
    while(true){

        Sleep(100);
        do{
            //here I make it nonblockin keypress
            //but actually we do not need it 
            //we can use blocking ReadConsoleInputA(h,IR,1,&read);
            //this way we not even need sleep() and 
            //our keypress function will be simple
            //anyway im posting nonblocking one

            //nonblocking keypress
            char key=0;
            bool isOk=keypress(key );

            if(!isOk ){ 
                Sleep(20);
                continue;
            }

            if(key>='0' && key<='9'){
                buffer[count]=key; 
                std::cout<<key;
                ++count;
                if( count==31)break;

            }

            // check Enter key and  enough symbol
            if(  key==13 && count>0  ){  
                std::cout<<std::endl;
                break;
            }

            //for windows 

            //check if Esc pressed
            if(key==27) exit(0); 


        }while(true);

        buffer[count]='\0';

        int value=atoi(buffer);
        return value;
    }
}
int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> mylist; 
    int value; 
    char buffer[100];
    //infinite loop
    while(true)
    {   
        //get number 
        value=cinnumb(); 
        mylist.push_back(value);
         //print  list
        std::cout<<"new list: { " ;
        for(int i=0;i< mylist.size();i++){
                std::cout<<mylist[i]<<'\t';
            }
        std::cout<<" }"<<std::endl;
        //sleep a little
        Sleep(10); 
    } ;


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: so how would it be implemented in my code. cin.get() will read a character my insertf function needs an int and above all i think cin.get cannot read the esc button

Comment: @Kostas mm just checked cin.get() as not giving escape character . so you have to do with winapi

Comment: just edited the original question so you can see what i understand from what you said

Comment: edited GetAsyncKeyState(27)==0 to GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE)==0 and it now seems to work THANK YOU

Comment: although on the first run i have to enter a list value before it closes any suggestion on how to solve that?

Comment: ok first i will have to understand how that works and if i don't solve it i will ask you, thanks again!

Comment: @Kostas posted you another two solutions check

Comment: That should be `GetAsyncKeyState(vk) & 0x8000`