# Using an ASCII value as a condition

Tags: c++, arrays, ascii

The following program should read some integer values from input and store them into an array until the user presses "Esc" key, but i cannot figure out how to do that. I have tried to use it's ASCII value as a condition but it doesn't work, or I'm doing something wrong.Could somebody please help me? Here is the code :

```
    void main(){
int i=0, a[MAX];
cout <<"Please enter several integer numbers and press Esc when you want to finish" << endl;
while ((i != char(27)) && (i < MAX)) {
     cin >> a[i];
    i++;
}
```

Comment: `main` returns `int`. What does "it doesn't worK" mean?

Comment: What is the check for `27` supposed to achieve?

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17174849/c-how-do-i-terminate-my-programm-using-esc-button

Comment: The "27" is the decimal value of Esc key in ASCII

Comment: @Georgiana: And `i` is the number of integers entered. So why are you comparing that count to the decimal value of the Esc key in ASCII? :-)

Comment: That's complicated. You need to change the way the terminal read the input but you will also lose the readline feature doing that. And  then you would read characters you can change to integers.

Comment: Doesn't work means that nothing happens when i press Esc. There is something else in the program but it doesn't move on to the further code.

Comment: Yeah i didnt think the console would read in the esc key?

Comment: You could just have the user type esc

Comment: Found another link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-2

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems here.  The first, and most important,
is that most systems will do line oriented input, which means
that they will pick up a lot of control characters (including,
probably, ESC) and do something with them internally, rather
than returning them to you; it might not even be possible to
ever see an ESC in the input.

For the rest, there are several problems with your code.  The
first is that you're testing against the index into the array
(where you'll put the next character), not against anything
you've read.  The second is that you're inputting `int`, so you
won't see any individual characters; just the results of the
conversion of your input.  (In fact, if an ESC character does
get through, you'll end up with `std::cin` in a error state.)
The third is that you never test whether the input has
succeeded.

A better solution would be to adopt some other convention for
the input: say one number per line, with an empty line signaling
the end.  In that case, you could write something like:

```
std::vector<int> a;
std::string line;
std::cout << "..." << std::endl;
while ( std::getline( std::cin, line ) && !line.empty() ) {
    std::istringstream parse( line );
    int value;
    parse >> value >> std::ws;
    if ( !parse ) {
        std::cout << "That wasn't an integer, try again" << std::endl;
    } else if ( parse.get() != EOF ) {
        std::cout << "Extra garbage at end of line, ignoring it" << std::endl;
    } else {
        a.push_back( value );
    }
}
```

(You'll note that I've used `std::vector`, since you don't know
up front how many inputs you'll get.)

If you really want to use ESC, you'll probably need a third
party library, along the lines of `curses`, to do raw input,
reading one character at a time, and collecting the digits into
a string, for conversion using `std::istringstream`.

Comment: The vector alternative is great but using Esc is imperative. Thank you for the hint!

Comment: @Georgiana Then you can't use `std::cin`.  I've just tested under Windows, and in a console window, at least, the escape key will never end up in the stream.  If you're not worried about portability, then perhaps `getch` could be used, but it could be tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Do not do this use James method its much better and will run on evrything but just for the sake of answering a question you can do this. This will not work on all platforms It works on visual c++ compiler.

```
  # include <iostream>
  # include <conio.h>
  # include <vector>

  using namespace std;




int main()

{

   char key;
   vector<int> a;
   int temp = 0;
   while ((key = getch()) != 27)
  {
     cin >> temp;
     a.push_back(temp); 
  }

  for (int i = 0 ; i < a.size() ; i++)
  {
 cout << a.at(i) << endl;
   }

    printf("Exit");
cout << endl;
system("Pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Edit: Programs clearer now. Note this program should not be used it is very platform and compiler dependant.

Comment: Is `<coonio.h>` still supported?!  (I remember this from the old days of MS-DOS, but I didn't know it was still around.)

Comment: Its working on my visual c++ 2012 compiler but I don't recommend it it'll only work on on windows i think

Comment: It's clearly windows specific.  On the other hand, I'm not sure how `getch` interacts with `std::cin`.  If I were to use it, I'd probably implement my own `getline` based on it, and use `std::istringstream` on it rather than try to mix `getch` and `std::cin <<`.

Comment: On using it the program waits for a key to be read in this is then stored to cIn (probably not the best name for the variable now that i think of it) it then uses cin >> to store user input to temp and then it stores temp to vector a. Theres a delay in entering values aswell because getch() must be executed first

Comment: Why the awful indentation?

Comment: Written off a phone. I find it hard to put code into it aswell I use the crtl k (enter code shortcut ) and then paste it in but it's coming up like normal text so I then have to put in the spaces manually do I think I'm doing it wrong?