# The C++ program should exit as soon as he presses 'esc'

Tags: c++, exit, cin

I have a program in which there is a code which looks something like this:

```
int Element[15];
cout << "Enter name/symbol of the Element: ";
cin >> Element;
```

and I want the program to exit as soon as he presses *'esc'* key. And also the user should not have to press the *'enter'* key after pressing the *'esc'* key. So how to do that??

Comment: windows or linux? I think either way it will require the use of a library outside iostreams, but on Linux at least you'll definitely have to turn off line buffering on the terminal which is a bit esoteric.

Comment: If this is not Windows, investigate `ncurses`.

Comment: I know of no way to do this within the boundaries of _just_ C++ (even C++11).  You will need to do something platform-specific.

Comment: FYI, `'\033'` is the character generated by `ESC` on almost all computers nowadays (the only exception worth worrying about is IBM rusty iron, where you might encounter EBCDIC).  And you can read that from `cin` just fine.  It is the not having to press 'enter' part that requires going beyond ISO C++.

Comment: This post might help you, looks similar [StackOverflow][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17174849/c-how-do-i-terminate-my-programm-using-esc-button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows you can do it using Windows API. GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE) helps you to check if Escape is pressed. You can try something like this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

  int Element[15];
  HANDLE h;

  do {  
    h = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    if(WaitForSingleObject(h, 0) == WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
      cout << "Enter name/symbol of the Element: ";
      cin >> Element;
    }
  } while(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE)==0);

  return 0;
}
```

I had the same problem and solved it that way above. This question helped me a lot (the handling idea is from the accepted answer): [C++ how do I terminate my programm using ESC button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17174849/c-how-do-i-terminate-my-programm-using-esc-button) . Another solutions for this problem are also provided in that question answer from the link.

That way of detecting Esc key should also work (however, I didn't test it properly):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int c = _getcha();
  while(c != 27) {
    // do stuff
    c = _getcha();
  }

  return 0;
}
```